# Why is my new SSD so slow to delete files? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, ssd, file-management

I recently replaced by 128GB SSD boot drive with a 1TB SSD so that I wouldn't run into as many problems with managing disk space. My process for doing this was to plug the new drive in, clone it with Macrium Reflect, resize the OS partition with EasyBCD (since the recovery partition was placed after the OS partition), and finally to add the new boot partition to the boot files using bcdboot.

However, once I booted into Windows 10 on the new drive, I noticed that moving and deleting would take much longer than on my old SSD. For instance, the amount of time it takes to delete a folder seems to be proportional to the amount of files in the folder, and not its total size. It even seems to reach speeds as low as half a MB per second at times. This is especially aggravating since I'm a programmer, and editing many small files is an integral part of many tools I use.

I've confirmed that TRIM is enabled and that the drive is about 17% full, so this probably isn't an issue with the drive being full or with Windows 10 mismanaging it.

What can I do to fix this behavior, short of reverting to my old boot drive?

Comment: Maybe try a different Windows User. I have a 2 TB Samsung SSD drive and disk copy, delete, move functions are not slow.

Comment: @John can you explain how switching to a different user would help in this situation? My current user account is the admin, so I'd have to create a new one to test this.

Comment: I am suggesting you try it. I have a 1 TB SSD on my laptop and 2 x 2 TB SSD drives on my desktop and no slowness as you describe. Changing Windows User uses a different profile that the one you cloned over.

Comment: @John I'll reformulate: creating a new user would take a significant amount of time due to the problem I'm experiencing, so I'd like to have some degree of confidence that attempting this might work. I don't understand why using a different profile would help at all here.

Comment: A new test user only takes minutes to create and test. I am merely suggesting testing. However, if you do not wish to test, then perhaps someone else has a better idea

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Files get deleted and moved exactly as slowly as on my normal account.

Comment: Thanks for the update - appreciated it. So (1) the clone may have gone wrong, or, (2) the SSD has a hardware problem or deficiency. You can see why I suggested the easy suggestion first. Good SSD drives are not slow - I am using them on a couple of machines of my own and lots at clients.

Comment: Have you checked the bios to make sure the sata port is setup correctly?

Comment: Old post, but for future visitors re _"the amount of time it takes to delete a folder seems to be proportional to the amount of files in the folder, and not its total size"_ - this is normal and expected. Deleting doesn't erase files, but just removes their entries. File size is irrelevant, only number of files matters.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with a new 4TB SSD. Quite often, deleting even an empty folder took seconds.

Then I found out that this happened when my NAS was off. It seems that Windows somehow tries to connect to offline mapped drives when I delete a file. Turning on or deleting the mapped drives solved my issue.

On a side note, creating/deleting/moving files and folders in OneDrive is often slow, even on a SSD. I gave up using OneDrive for work in progress at home and at the office. I now work on a-non OneDrive folder tree and archive (zip) my work to OneDrive every week or so.